# Como actualizar los registros siguientes de un registro seleccionado ? MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de movimientos  y quiero que cuando actualice un registro pasado todos los registros siguientes se re calculen:

Tengo estos registros en esta tabla (la linea negra tapa un dato que no tiene anda que ver):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy editando el primer regitro.
En el formulario estaria enviando :

> CantMov = 10

valoringresa = 12,500.00 (Esta valor es el mismo para valStockI)

y ahora, como antes el dato Cantmov era 20  lo resto que el que acabo de ingresar , de igual forma el valoringresa

CantMov = 20 - 10 (Este 10  estaria restando  a todos los stockActual de los siguientes registros)

valoringresa  = 25,000.00 - 12,500.00 (Este 12,500.00  estaria restando  a todos los valStockI de los siguientes registros)

Estoy intentando que quede así :

```html
<table border=1>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>cantMov</td>
<td>valoringresa</td>
<td>stockActual</td>
<td>valStockI</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>12,500.00</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>12,500.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>12,500.00</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>25,000.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>12,500.00</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>12,500.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Pero  me sale mal el la columna valStockI

En todos los regitros me pone el mismo valor  : 12,500.00

puse unos sout en las consultas y me mostro esto :

(Primera vuelta)

```
update_valStockI : UPDATE movimientos set valStockI='25,000.00 '  where idMovimiento > 2 and idStockI= 2 and valStockI ='37,500.00'
```

(Segunda vuelta)

```
update_valStockI : UPDATE movimientos set valStockI='12,500.00 '  where idMovimiento > 2 and idStockI= 2 and valStockI ='25,000.00'
```

**Se donde esta el error pero no se como solucionarlo**

**El error es que en la primera vuelta actualiza correctamente pero en el segundo como el dato que tenia 37,500.00 se convirtio en 25,000.00 tambien lo actualiza con los otros registros convirtiendolo en 12,500.00**

**El código que uso es este: **

```js
<!--SELECCIONO LOS VALORES A ACTUALIZAR-->
String query_valStockI = "SELECT valStockI FROM movimientos where idMovimiento > " + mod.getIdMovimiento() + " and idStockI= " + mod.getIdStockI() + "";


try{
  Statement st_valorIngresar = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs_valorIngresar = st_valorIngresar.executeQuery(query_valStockI);
 while (rs_valorIngresar.next()) {
 double total = Double.parseDouble(rs_valorIngresar.getString(1).replace(",", ""));
double totalfinal = total + valoringresaplus;
String totalfinal_ = nf.format(totalfinal).replace("$", "");
<!--rs_valorIngresar.getString(1) es igual a "37,500.00" del ejemplo de  arriba-->

String update_valStockI = "UPDATE movimientos set valStockI='" + totalfinal_ + " ' where idMovimiento > " + mod.getIdMovimiento() + " and idStockI= " + mod.getIdStockI() + " and valStockI ='" + rs_valorIngresar.getString(1) + "' ";
 try {
 ps_valStockI = con.prepareStatement(update_valStockI);
 ps_valStockI.execute();
 } catch (SQLException e)
 {
 System.err.println(e);
  return false;
  }
   }
                    
}catch (SQLException e) {
                            System.err.println(e);
                            return false;
                        }
```

**Si necesitan mas información o no entendieron algo me avisan por favor , no tengo idea de como poder solucionar este problema**

Comment: Empecemos por definir que es el registro siguiente. La base de datos no conoce el concepto de registro siguiente. A que te referis con eso?

Comment: Osea yo  selecciono Dos id que es  IdMovimiento(Primary Key)  y idStockI(Id de otra tabla)  la idStockI se repiten en varios registros y  en un select los agrupo por esa id  , bueno quiero editar todos los registros que que tengan una idMovimiento mayor a la que e seleccionado siempre y cuando tengan la misma idStockI que el registro que seleccione

Comment: @gbianchi  por eso en  la sentencia Select y UPDATE uso  idmovimiento > $id

Comment: Ok.. eso no lo habias aclarado... Creo que tu query se soluciona si cambias el where por:  where idMovimiento = idMovimiento+1 and idStockI= 2. Y deberias guardar cual fue el ultimo moviemiento que cambiaste. probalo de esa forma... si no vas a tener que hacer lo que haces ahora, pero al reves.. de menos a mayor...